# Bookmarklet on blank page

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, window.open

I've written a simple bookmarklet that opens multiple web pages with a single click:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");window.open("http://www.google.com");window.open("http://www.yahoo.com");})();
```

I wan't to be able to open the browser and click this immediately, but the bookmarklet won't work unless a page is already loaded in the window.  I prefer to have my browser home page set to "Blank" for speed.  Is there a way to make this bookmarklet execute without a page already loaded?

Also, I'd like the bookmarklet to replace whatever page is loaded in the window, if something is indeed loaded.  At present, it opens 3 new tabs.  I've tried the "_self" and "_parent" values for the "name" attribute on the first window.open, but it doesn't seem to work.  I may not be formatting it correctly.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? Your bookmarklet works for me in Firefox 14 on "about:blank".

Comment: Chrome for Mac Version 21.0.1180.79 here.  Apparently, the blank page on Chrome is not a valid HTML page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible to open bookmarklet in no page.

Instead, you can try to set your homepage to something like `data:text/html,Welcome!` (yes, it IS a working URL).

To open a page in the same tab, type:

```
location.href='http://www.w3schools.com'
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try that.  I'll investigate the location.href method further.

Comment: 'data:text/html,Welcome!' does allow me to execute the code.  Thank you!

Comment: `about:blank` works as well in Chrome

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and learned from the internet that if you go to your about:config, search for **browser.newtab.url** and change it to **about:blank** instead of the default **about:newtab** your javascript bookmarklets should work (just tried, and it's working!). This should be cleaner than doing a data:text/html message (in any case even if you set the homepage it doesn't work for every new tab, only once for a new window)

Comment: This no longer works. Instead see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1086817 for some addons that will work. Or you can use the "Classic Theme Restorer" and it has a setting for this.

Comment: This apparently applies to FireFox and not Chrome.