# In Chrome "javascript:window.open" on a blank tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

On Chrome, I created links in the Bookmarks tab.
I wanted them to open in a new tab rather than overwriting the existing tab.
So the bookmark I made were

```
javascript:window.open("https://example.com")
```

and not directly

```
https://example.com
```

It works fine, but when I launch it on a new tab (completly blank), that doen't do anything, the site isn't loaded

Is there a way to make that work even on a blank tab ? (creating a new tab or overwriting it, indifferently)

Comment: Sorry - I'm removing my answer because I misunderstood your question. I'm not sure what you're trying is possible [without changing your homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206017/12652373)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the informations given by Driftr95, I succeeded.
I didn't change anything in my bookmark, but changer the new tab tyo a blank page.
For that I used an extension on Chrome:  "New Tab Redirect", with the option "Blank page"